# Php loop merge arrays first value and create new string

Tags: php

I have multiple file upload form and I get files name with php loop;

```
for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i]);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
   echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i]). " has been uploaded.";}
    }
```

When the loop finishes, I want to create a string with combining uploaded files name and I will store on my database as a string;

I assume 3 files uploaded

$_FILES["upload"]["name"][0], $_FILES["upload"]["name"][1], $_FILES["upload"]["name"][2]

image1.jpeg,image2.jpeg,image3.jpeg

Comment: `$string.=$_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i].',';` in the loop

Comment: @tim thank you it works but there is a comma at the end of string. I remove that with this code; $string = rtrim($string, ",");

Answer (score 0):

Push them onto an array, then call `implode()` at the end.

```
$filenames = [];
for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
        $filenames[] = basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$i]);
    }
}
echo "The files " . implode(", ", $filenames) . " have been uploaded.";
```